# Are MD5, SHA-256, SHA-512 suitable for calculating hash values of large files?

Tags: c#, .net, md5, sha256, sha512

Here is a function that shall calculate hash values for files. But I always get wrong hash codes from time to time.

```
string filePath = @"G:\TV\movie.ts"; // about 10 GByte
private void Test()
{

  for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
  {
    byte[] bytes;
    try
    {
      var SHA256 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256.Create();
      var MD5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
      var SHA512 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512.Create();
      using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
      {
        stream.Position = 0;
        bytes = MD5.ComputeHash(stream);
        Debug.Print(i + ": " + BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", ""));

        stream.Position = 0;
        bytes = SHA256.ComputeHash(stream);
        Debug.Print(i + ": " + BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", ""));

        stream.Position = 0;
        bytes = SHA512.ComputeHash(stream);
        Debug.Print(i + ": " + BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", ""));
      }
      MD5.Dispose();
      SHA256.Dispose();
      SHA512.Dispose();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      Debug.Print(e.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

Result for one large file (movie ~10GB).
For MD5 (short) and SHA256 (middle) I marked the deviations bold.
When you look at the SHA512 (long) results you'll see that from the 8x I performed the test, I got
4x1B04E14AD6A0D1CC9D131D37D92C90146C118655B50935033A67BC0F436E9CAC424B569CCDB392D12B477DA751F30CD677023D78A55AA3CC97F8F8CD9F941D97
3xF9A6C6C61579FF989F17FB78DD23F1A4B6290588002EE58FB2C9427C75DD35D4745D15DB868CFCC94A49C9227E6C058FB89E862E50E8A06C527FC8C72EDCAFC7
1x1A3050206C8F3E94FC918F140215ADF2A9F463EAF083D421F5AF3FC450A634E9DF04C62889C3F295D504DDE34014CEF4A908C01D26770E250311816F77826B23

That shows, that when it goes wrong, it often results in the same wrong hash.

***So the question is, why do I get wrong results with every algorythm from time to time?***

0: 920651841DF511BC45B51DABF76F08D8
0: ADA7EDB960A0EBB298E6BAB8FBF5E2C3D7D2E170B2C19B0B6432A469F2A398B7
0: 1B04E14AD6A0D1CC9D131D37D92C90146C118655B50935033A67BC0F436E9CAC424B569CCDB392D12B477DA751F30CD677023D78A55AA3CC97F8F8CD9F941D97

1: 920651841DF511BC45B51DABF76F08D8
1: ADA7EDB960A0EBB298E6BAB8FBF5E2C3D7D2E170B2C19B0B6432A469F2A398B7
1: 1A3050206C8F3E94FC918F140215ADF2A9F463EAF083D421F5AF3FC450A634E9DF04C62889C3F295D504DDE34014CEF4A908C01D26770E250311816F77826B23

2: 920651841DF511BC45B51DABF76F08D8
2: ADA7EDB960A0EBB298E6BAB8FBF5E2C3D7D2E170B2C19B0B6432A469F2A398B7
2: 1B04E14AD6A0D1CC9D131D37D92C90146C118655B50935033A67BC0F436E9CAC424B569CCDB392D12B477DA751F30CD677023D78A55AA3CC97F8F8CD9F941D97

3: **944638B455C6C4DBF1B4149B16360C4E**
3: ADA7EDB960A0EBB298E6BAB8FBF5E2C3D7D2E170B2C19B0B6432A469F2A398B7
3: F9A6C6C61579FF989F17FB78DD23F1A4B6290588002EE58FB2C9427C75DD35D4745D15DB868CFCC94A49C9227E6C058FB89E862E50E8A06C527FC8C72EDCAFC7

4: 920651841DF511BC45B51DABF76F08D8
4: ADA7EDB960A0EBB298E6BAB8FBF5E2C3D7D2E170B2C19B0B6432A469F2A398B7
4: 1B04E14AD6A0D1CC9D131D37D92C90146C118655B50935033A67BC0F436E9CAC424B569CCDB392D12B477DA751F30CD677023D78A55AA3CC97F8F8CD9F941D97

5: 920651841DF511BC45B51DABF76F08D8
5: **03DD7ADCA595F925E9226D1022D2FFB06F59710677E01472E4267E635DC4020A**
5: F9A6C6C61579FF989F17FB78DD23F1A4B6290588002EE58FB2C9427C75DD35D4745D15DB868CFCC94A49C9227E6C058FB89E862E50E8A06C527FC8C72EDCAFC7

6: 920651841DF511BC45B51DABF76F08D8
6: ADA7EDB960A0EBB298E6BAB8FBF5E2C3D7D2E170B2C19B0B6432A469F2A398B7
6: 1B04E14AD6A0D1CC9D131D37D92C90146C118655B50935033A67BC0F436E9CAC424B569CCDB392D12B477DA751F30CD677023D78A55AA3CC97F8F8CD9F941D97

7: **945F30E57094D2725B727D69F7BE7F4C**
7: ADA7EDB960A0EBB298E6BAB8FBF5E2C3D7D2E170B2C19B0B6432A469F2A398B7
7: F9A6C6C61579FF989F17FB78DD23F1A4B6290588002EE58FB2C9427C75DD35D4745D15DB868CFCC94A49C9227E6C058FB89E862E50E8A06C527FC8C72EDCAFC7

Comment: You probably have a faulty disk... hash algorithms are deterministic. Same input == same output.

Comment: The wall of text containing the hashes doesn't really add much to the question.  We believe you, the hashes are sometimes different.

Comment: I really don't believe in a faulty disk, because you can see in the task manager, that the file is only loaded 1 time from disk (disk activity 100% for some time). All repetitive file reads are performed out of the RAM. Windows caches it automatically. Never the less, I get the same results when running it from other disks. Vor small files up to a few MB I never saw this happening.

Comment: My initial thought was the streams buffer isn't getting cleared when setting the position.  But that's an issue with `StreamReader` (solved by calling `DiscardBufferedData()`), not `FileStream`.  So I'm not sure.

Comment: @be_mi Then it could be faulty ram. Improbable but not impossible.

Comment: To reduce the possibility of this being a framework/JIT bug, open different streams per hash calculation instead of resetting the position. Also, try running the executable as a whole in a little `cmd`/PowerShell loop 99 times, instead of having it do 99 calculations on its own. Also, per xanatos, do not discount the possibility of hardware failure -- a single faulty bit in a single RAM chip could completely change hash values without ever causing a problem in a real application.

Comment: @bommelding: yes, it should work -- my point is that if the code works when reopening the file (and we know that the hardware isn't broken, which is still a big if), then we've definitely found a problem in the framework/JIT and also a lead to investigate. "Normal" code isn't likely to recycle a stream that way, so we would expect the bug not to manifest in those circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, as stated in some comments, that it was a hardware problem. After resetting the BIOS, it seems to work all right again.

Comment: Ah, overclocking. Always so much fun.